# SQL query for grouping data from two tables

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have 3 tables:

- Users (id, name)
- Orders (id, userId)
- Orders_Items (id, orderId, status)

At first I wanted to list all users with their respective count of orders like this:

- A, 1 order
- B, 5 orders

That's easy, I'm doing a "select name, count(id) from users, orders where users.id = orders.userId group by name".

Now, I'd like to further filter this data to show only users with orders that have items with status = "unprocessed". I am not sure how to go about grouping data from 2 tables. In the end, I'm looking to get data like:

- (A not shown, no order with any item having status = unprocessed)
- B, 3 orders (2 orders have no item with status = unprocessed).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something like this: SELECT name, count(id) from users, orders,orders_items WHERE users.id= orders.userId and orders.id=orders_items.orderid and order_items.status='unprocessed' GROUP BY name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT u.name,
         COUNT(o.id) AS numOrders
    FROM USERS u
    JOIN ORDERS o ON o.userid = u.id
   WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                  FROM ORDERS_ITEMS oi 
                 WHERE oi.orderid = o.id
                   AND oi.status = 'unprocessed')
GROUP BY u.name
```

Using a JOIN to `ORDERS_ITEMS` would require the use of DISTINCT in the COUNT:

```
  SELECT u.name,
         COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) AS numOrders
    FROM USERS u
    JOIN ORDERS o ON o.userid = u.id
    JOIN ORDERS_ITEMS oi ON oi.orderid = o.id
                        AND oi.status = 'unprocessed'
GROUP BY u.name
```

...because of row duplication when there are more than one unprocessed item to an order...

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I used the second method as the first one was about 10 times slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, count(users.id) from users 
left join orders 
on users.id=orders.userId 
left join orders_items 
on orders.id=orders_items.orderId 
where orders_items.status="unprocessed"
```

I'm testing this now, not quite sure if I have it right.
Edit: seems good.

Comment: You don't want to use an OUTER join if you want to exclude things from the result set.